# Excel 'average.if' function returns only first value instead of average

Tags: excel, function, average

So I have an Excel file with 3 worksheets. On the 3rd one I want to calculate averages for my raw data present in the first one.

The raw data table is structured in columns, the first column consists of categories, all the other ones of scores related to a particular question (one question per column).

I want to calculate the average for all the scores one 4 questions/columns (columns K-N), but only if the category in column J corresponds to a give value.

This is my function:

```
=AVERAGE.IF('Raw data'!J:J;"category 1"; 'Raw data'!K:N)
```

My function only returns the first value of all values in columns K:N. It does select on the correct category (so the .IF part seems to work) but doesn't calculate an average.

Who can help me out?

Comment: do you mean `AVERAGEIF` without the period? What language are you running?

Comment: I'm running in Dutch, where it is =GEMIDDELDE.ALS; so in English I guess it will be =AVERAGEIF, yep.

Answer (score 0):

The first and the third parameter are ranges and need to be of the same shape. Your first range is a single column, but the range in your third parameter has four columns. That is invalid syntax and the function will not work.

You need to to an AverageIF for each of the four columns and then average the four numbers, like:

```
=average(AVERAGEIF('Raw data'!J:J;"category 1"; 'Raw data'!K:K);AVERAGEIF('Raw data'!J:J;"category 1"; 'Raw data'!L:L);AVERAGEIF('Raw data'!J:J;"category 1"; 'Raw data'!M:M);AVERAGEIF('Raw data'!J:J;"category 1"; 'Raw data'!N:N))
```

In order top prevent errors caused by different languages and regions, don't copy the formula from above. Create the formula in your Excel.